# Field function return the right results but $params->get return an array full of NULLS

Tags: joomla-2.5, development, form-fields-types

I had a full working module that was parsing some values from a dropdownlist at backend and it was editing those values at frontend.

Yesterday a co-worker changed something and today it doesnt work. After a bit of debugging, I found out that the list returns the results, but when I try to parse them from the program through $params->get, I take an array[8] (I selected 8 things ) full of NULLS;

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');
class JFormFieldManulist extends JFormFieldList
{
    protected $type = 'Manulist';
    protected function getOptions()
    {


     $db= JFactory::getDbo();
     $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__virtuemart_manufacturers_en_gb'); 
        $db->setQuery($query);
     $items = $db->loadObjectList();
         $options = array();
            $counter=0;
         if ($items)
         {
          foreach($items as $item)
          {
            $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $item->virtuemart_manufacturer_id , $item->mf_name,$item->slug);
            $counter++;
          }
         }
          $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);
         var_dump($counter);
         var_dump($options); --> returns expected result         
         return $options;


    }
}
```

controller:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$doc                                = JFactory::getDocument();
$moduleclass_sfx                    = $params->get('moduleclass_sfx');
$layout                             = $params->get('layout', 'default');
$moduleName                         = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$fmanuf                             = $params->get('foreignmanuf');
var_dump($fmanuf); ---> return NULLS
```

XML:

```
<fieldset name="brand_params" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_manufacturers/fields" >            
<field name="foreignmanuf" type="Manulist"   label="Foreign Brands" multiple="true"  description="Foreign Brands" />
```

What could be the problem that, even if the function returns the desired results , the controller cant get em ?

Comment: I assume the code at the bottom belongs in a separate file yes?

Comment: yeap its in the mod_modulename.php file

Comment: Does your co-worker remember what he/she changed? Do you have a backup of the site with this code which was working before?

Comment: he was trying to study the code to mimic the methodology for a different module. He said he dont remember changing something.
I had a backup but i accidentaly overwrited before 1 week .

Comment: I can't personally see anything wrong with your code, however it's still the morning so my eyes will most likely be playing tricks on me. What I would suggest doing is using `var_dump()` after every variable starting with your database query results. When you get to a point where it shows `null`, report that code snippet back here. I would also suggest you tell your co-worker never to start messing around with code on a production website for testing purposes and always to take a backup. Why he started fiddling with the live code I have no idea, stupid mistake

Comment: I actually did that, i used var_dump() on every variable inside the function. and every return was allright. The first variable tha returns NULL is the $fmanuf=$params->get('foreignmanuf');
We working alot of guys in the same site , doing different things. Could something else make the module not work ? like a variable collision etc ? gonna add and the xml that defines the custom field also , maybe is something wrong there and i cant see it.

Comment: Try to dump `$params`. Does it contain your custom param?

Comment: Nope. i get this:
{"foreignmanuf":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],"manufimages":["","","","","","","",""],"manucounter":"","selectedlist":""}

Comment: After i select some names and click save at backend every single record is getting selected O.O

Comment: I am concerned that your list is not saved at all. The param `foreignmanuf` is empty. Something wrong with the selectlist.

Comment: but then the $options[] array would be empty also, right ?